# Can I bundle the common module when bundling in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, module, webpack

Question about webpack. When bundling modules with webpack Runs the application based on location at the entry point. At this time, when the entry point is set to multiple, a file that is built by the number of entry points is created.

If bundles are bundled into Web packs on an entry basis, they can be bundled into bundles A and B. At this time, I used a module called HELLO in A bundle and a module called HELLO in B module.

At this time, when bundling with the web pack, only the modules used in common (HELLO module) are bundled separately.

Can I make A bundle, B bundle, H bundle? What I want to call H bundle in A bundle and make it available.

Below is my webpack code. I using multiple entries to multiple bundle

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: ['./public/js/index.ts', './public/js/admin/member.ts'],
    output: {
        path: 'dist/public/js',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                transpileOnly: true
            }
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    A: ['./public/js/index.ts'],
    B: ['./public/js/admin/member.ts']
  },
  output: {
    path: 'dist/public/js',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
            transpileOnly: true
        }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  plugins: [
     new CommonsChunkPlugin({
     name: 'H',
     minChunks: 2
   })
};
```

webpack will make A.js, B.js, and H.js where H.js will have shared modules that A and B use. But H would have to be included first via script tag before including A and B

Something like this?